# Rendering Revit files to a graphics surface in a Windows Forms/WPF app

Tags: winforms, autodesk, revit

I noted on AutoDesk forum post that there are commercial SDKs that allow you do read/write/render DWG files within your Windows Forms application. http://www.woutware.com/cadlib/4.0/pricing.html is one example.

Are there Commercial SDKs to read/write/render AutoDesk Revit files within your application?
I have asked on an AutoDesk forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Revit file are just too complex to be viewed outside the original software and there are no open standards/reverse engineered libraries. 
So the only think I can suggest you is to browse this archive:

http://www.redbolts.com/blog/page/Downloads.aspx

N.B. I know that you don't need just a (revit) file simple thumbnail, but a possibility to view/zoom it etc